# How can I fix these ngons into quads?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

Ive used the bevel tool to create an arch on my object but naturally an ngon was created on the edges. How can I fix this ngon while also keeping it in quads? Ive tried insetting the face and then using grid fill and i want to avoid triangulation as much as possible.

Comment: Personally I think, those are n-gons, but it's quite clean geometry and I wouldn't change it. It's a myth that everything needs to be quads, and creating insets, grid fill etc. will only result in unnecessary high poly count in a simple area... If you prefer quads okay, that's your choice. If you think you have to make quads, I recommend videos by Josh Gambrell on that topic e.g. this: [Why ngons are BETTER than quads for hard surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svS9V2iAesA) or this one [SUBD vs. NGON modeling - which is the right choice?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsubUPuRlgU)

Comment: Typically im ok with ngons if its for a render but in this case its for a game engine (Unity) and game engines dont work well with ngons at all unfortunately

Comment: If it's not for Blender, but for a game engine - why avoid triangulation? The faces get triangulated anyway for rendering, and sometimes it's better to have control over the triangulation beforehand to make "nice" triangles instead of having quads and n-gons triangulated  randomly in the game engine.